# Не могу настроить цель на Java-событие (клик по номеру телефона) на сайте Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, яндекс-метрика

Вставлял такой код в ссылку

```
<a href="tel:+799999999" onclick="ym(50000000, 'reachGoal', 'calltosite'); return true;">+7(999)999-99-99</a>
```

Метрика не регистрирует, видимо надо еще что-то настроить, но самостоятельно не могу найти информацию.

Извиняюсь за глупый вопрос)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к WordPress. Вы самой Метрике цель добавили? Валидатором смотрите?

Comment: в метрике javascript-событие calltosite, номер счетчика указан правильно

Comment: Замазали данные на скриншоте, но показали в коде))

Comment: в коде данные не правильные указаны

Comment: Ну так там ещё метрики нет.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду? Если код самого счетчика, то он вставлен и работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Смотрите](https://yandex.ru/blog/metrika-club/gid-po-metrike-kak-proverit-rabotu-tseli) официальное руководство по проверке работы целей, а для тестирования работы целей и вывода отладочной информации достаточно для любого урла на вашем сайте добавить GET параметр `_ym_debug=1`, например так: `https://www.example.com/?_ym_debug=1&foo=bar`.